# Misconception of how memory is created using malloc()/calloc()

Tags: c, memory-management

My concept of the way `malloc()/calloc()` create memory has always been that once an item is created, the address of the object stays the same.  But a function I often use to create an array of strings, and one that seems to have always worked well, recently caused me to question my understanding, that is, memory addresses of objects *can be (and are) moved* simply by calling `calloc/malloc`.

To illustrate, here is the function I have used to create memory for an array of strings - `char **`:

```
char ** CreateArrayOfStrings(char **a, int numWords, int maxWordLen)
{
    int i;
    a = calloc(numWords, sizeof(char *));   //create array of pointers
    if(!a) return a;                        //required caller to check for NULL
    for(i=0;i<numWords;i++)
    {
        a[i] = calloc(maxWordLen + 1, 1);   //create memory for each string 
    }
    return a;
}
```

On my system, (Win7, 32bit compile, ANSI C) The line:

```
a = calloc(numWords, sizeof(char *));   //create array of pointers
```

Creates a block of contiguous memory, sized for *numWords* `char *`, in this case 7, yielding 28 bytes:

[image]

Memory spans from address 0x03260080 + 1C (0x0326009C)
Or:

```
a[0] is at 0x3200260080    
a[1] is at 0x3200260084    
a[2] is at 0x3200260088    
a[3] is at 0x320026008C
a[4] is at 0x3200260090    
a[5] is at 0x3200260094    
a[6] is at 0x3200260098
```

Then, I create memory for each of `numWords` (7) strings

```
for(i=0;i<numWords;i++)
{
    a[i] = calloc(maxWordLen + 1, 1);   //maxWordLen == 5 in this example
}
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

This shows that the memory locations of the pointers `a[1] - a[6]` have been changed.

Can someone explain how/why this happens in `malloc()/calloc()`?

Comment: `*a = calloc(numWords, sizeof(char *));`

Comment: why does that show the pointers have changed?

Comment: @wildplasser - ?, is that a correction or an explanation?

Comment: ignore wildplasser --- he makes no sense.  I want to know why you think memory has changed -- are you objecting to the allocated memory not being continuous?

Comment: @yellowantphil - no.  He is allocated for the pointers not the content.

Comment: @Hogan - The addresses of each of the strings, accessible by `a[i]` notation have all changed.  eg.  a[2] was `0x3200260088` but after the second block of code, it is shown as `0x032600F0`.  That to me looks like an indication that address of `a[2]` has changed.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: assigning to a (the function's parameter) makes no sense: the changes to a's value will not be seen by the caller. (that is the reason that the char pointer is passed by reference, as `char **a` )

Comment: @wildplasser - wrong the `a` is returned from the function.

Comment: @wildplasser pretty sure that's the reason for the `return a;` though I admit its a bit odd.

Comment: @ryyker - I see.  I it is not that `a[2]` changed, it is that `a[2]` was "undefined" or random before the call to malloc.

Comment: The `return a;` makes the a as a function argument completely useless (and effectively unused)

Comment: @wildplasser - true.  But it is consistent with other C APIs

Comment: @Hogan - re: _"undefined" or random before the call to malloc._.  At the point I made the first call to calloc, I believe `*(a + i)`, for all `i` existed.  And were all accessible by using a[i].  Each one had a memory location (just not memory space), or it could not have been used in the second call to `malloc()`.  Is that not true?

Comment: While you're at it, your terminology might be hampering your understanding: memory is not "created" by malloc(). Your memory is there already, and will be there after free(). Malloc() simply marks it as belonging to you in the interval.

Comment: @wildplasser - creating the prototype the way I did allows me to create and destroy `a` in the calling function a little easier than if it was just a return.  It also simplifies things in the `Create` function.

Comment: And the caller just passes a NULL pointer as the first argument? Or a special *pointer du jour* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig - re: _a bit odd_.  Assume you are referring to the variable being acted on in both the return, and as an argument.  I have seen very similar things in other C APIs.  Why, exactly is it a bit odd to see it here?

Comment: @wildplasser - Yes, that is the way I use it.  i.e. ***1)*** `char **a = NULL;`, ***2)*** `a = CreateArrayOfStrings(a, 10, 10);`  ***3)*** use `a`, ***4)*** destroy `a`.  Makes creation, use, and cleanup very simple.

Comment: @ryyker It is odd because the passed-in value of `a` is  utterly useless (figuratively and literally). Were it participating in a `realloc()` or a `free()` + `calloc()` -or- `malloc()` it would make considerably more sense.  But the very first thing done in the posted code with that value is an overwrite, thereby making the parameter value passed worthless, and with that the figurative value of the parameter itself equally worthless. *That* is the reason it is odd.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - Agreed, it is likely that the words I have become comfortable with in explaining things to myself in this case have actually contributed to my confusion in this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I will experiment with a different prototype next time.  The shape of the prototype however is really incidental to what I was, and still am trying to learn from asking the question.  Always appreciate your comments, thanks.

Comment: @ryyker as I said, your prototype makes much more sense if the caller's passed in value is actually *used*. Such a use would be calling with a pointer guaranteed to be NULL or a prior return value from this function and foisting a `realloc()` strategy. Otherwise it is simply an odd place to put what is effectively a local variable and putting the onus on the caller to pass something that will never make a difference anyway. Perhaps a `realloc()` strategy was what you had in mind all along and simply haven't gotten there yet. Anyway, just brain-food. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig - an API like this allows for such features in the future without a change to the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that you are comparing apples to oranges:

- When you print `a[i] is at ...` pointers, you show the *addresses* of elements inside the array `a`
- However, when you shoe the memory layout, you show the *values* at these addresses, which are themselves pointers, so the whole picture looks confusing.

If you print the values at `a[i]` before assigning `calloc` results to them, you should get all zeros, because `calloc` `NULL`s out the memory. After the assignments, you see pointers to 6-byte blocks at each `a[i]`, which makes perfect sense.

To summarize, your initial understanding of what happens when you allocate memory with `malloc` and `calloc` is correct: once a chunk of memory is allocated, its address<sup>*</sup> remains the same.

<sup>*</sup> On systems with virtual memory, I should say "its virtual address".

Comment: I think what you are saying is correct, and indeed, when I view the actual memory of that block of 28 bytes, it is filled with zeros.  But I can also see in my resource manager, a tool in my environment, (that I may be misinterpreting) indicates what I assumed were addresses of the 7 pointers (a[0] - a[6]).  At that point, I have assigned no value to those locations, just allocated memory.  Is the image with red dots in my post not indicating memory addresses?

Comment: @ryyker Since you have an array of pointers, two addresses are in play here: (1) the address of the array element itself, i.e. `&a[0], &a[1], ...` and (2) the address stored at that address, i.e. `a[0], a[1], ...`. The first set of addresses never changes, because they are computed as offsets from `a`, which is the same as `&a[0]`. The second set of addresses changes when you assign values to `a[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

The memory of those addresses has not been changed. You are creating a 28-byte large block of space (`a`) and then at each element, dynamically allocating a second 6-byte block of space with *its own address*.

In other words, at a[1] (memory address `0x03260084`), the value that is **stored** there is a pointer to memory address `0x32600D0`.

To check the memory locations and the values at each one, try this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
{
    printf("a[%d] %p %p\n",i,&(a[i]),a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That is a good test.  It, in conjunction with @dasblinkenlight's comments I think will address my question.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `calloc(numWords, sizeof(char *))` you ask the operating system to allocate `numWords` pointers of size ``4 bytes each, on your system'', which is why the resulting block is `4 * numWords` bytes, and it returns the address to the first one of them. So now you can store the addresses of the pointers that will hold the actual data. The nth call to `calloc(maxWordLen + 1, 1)` will then return the address to a block of size `maxWordLen` and store it at the memory location pointed to by `a[n]` which is simply the address returned by the first call to `calloc` plus `n * sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: In looking at your (and others) comments, _now you can store the addresses of the pointers that will hold the actual data_ I believe is central to my misconception. Still noodling it, but thanks for your answer